# Vue JavaScript create variable from an other variable value

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I can't find how to create a variable from another variable value.

I get this variable from AJAX call (using `vue-resources`):

```
langs: {1:'fr', 2:'en', 3:'ar'},
```

But, I don't know how many properties `langs` will have.

How can I get this variable dynamically:

```
newVar: {
  has_lang: '1',
  values: [{ is: 'fr', val:''}, { is: 'en', val:''}, { is: 'ar', val:''}]
},
```

So in `newVar`, the `fr`, `en`, and `ar` properties have been generated automatically using the values in `langs`.

I am planning to use the `values` array to bind to the values of my `md-input` inputs using v-model:

```
<md-input-container v-for="value in newVar.values">
  <label>@{{ attribute.attribute }} @{{ value.is }}</label>
  <md-input v-model="value.val"></md-input>
</md-input-container>
```

Is doing this manipulation the best practice? Because I can't find a solution which uses `v-model` for inputs that are generated from a `v-for` loop.

Comment: That `values` isn't a valid JavaScript property. Is that supposed to be an array?

Comment: Can you explain more the question please?

Comment: That line: `values: { is: 'fr', fr:''}, { is: 'en', en:''}, { is: 'ar', ar:''}` is not valid JavaScript. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: A javascript object

Comment: @Codinga Probably `values: [{ is: 'fr', fr:''}, { is: 'en', en:''}, { is: 'ar', ar:''}]`

Comment: Please can you check the update? I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a watcher to set the `newVar` property whenever the `langs` property changes. You'll need to also do this during the `mounted` lifecycle event if you are passing in the `langs` variable as a prop or defining it within `data()`.

In your case, I'd add a method to call at both points:

```
data() {
  return {
    langs: {1:'fr', 2:'en', 3:'ar'},
    newVar: {},
  };
},
methods: {
  updateValues() {
    let newVar = {
      has_lang: (this.langs !== {}) ? '1' : '0',
      values: [],
    };

    for (let lang in this.langs) {
      newVar.values.push({ is: this.langs[lang], val: '' });
    }

    this.newVar = newVar;
  }
},
watch: {
  langs() {
    this.updateValues();
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.updateValues();
}
```

[Here's a CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpNzyx?editors=1010)

Comment: Great it seems to be what i want, Please one moment i will test it

Comment: I edit this line value[this.langs[lang]] = ''; by value[val] = ''; Because i need to use this object in inputs, I will edit my question please see edited version to understand more. I can't get val of my newVar edited when i show them in my html @{{ newVar }}

Comment: Please can you check my question again? It's updated

Comment: So in my inputs v-model what i must put?

Comment: @Codinga Sorry, I just fixed a typo in my answer. What you have written in your question will work.

Comment: Unfortunatly [ { "is": "fr", "val": "" }, { "is": "en", "val": "" }, { "is": "ar", "val": "" } ]
 still empty

Comment: @Codinga Ok you apparently couldn't bind to the `v-model` because it was a computed property. I updated my answer to use a watcher instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141372/discussion-between-codinga-and-thanksd).